# Passing Objects between Windows and Android / Which Serializer could do this?

Tags: java, android, windows, serialization, xml-serialization

i'm generating several large Hashmaps and putting them into 1 object on Windows (using Java). Now i want to transfer this object to my Android app by giving it as an Asset.

I have tried using the Java serialization, but when i unpack the object in my App, all hashmaps have null values.

My custom classes all implement Serialzable and contain basic types or other custom classes. (which contain basic types or other custom classes, and so on, the chain does end, its not a circle).

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Or does anyone know a XMLSerializer(or other) that supports flattening private fields without getters and setters?

Comment: If your keys and values are serializable, you *can* serialize a hashmap.

Comment: anything i use is serializable, i thought it could be problem with passing the object between the different systems...

Comment: Are you passing the binary files without problems (you could check their hash) ? This should work if you have the same classes versions.

Comment: Another solution would be to use protocol buffer. I find it to be more elegant than java standard serialization mechanism.

Comment: @dystroy I will check the hashes, good idea. I didn't even know there is such a thing as protocol buffer, but wikipedia info sounds good to me. I will check taht too. Thanks !

Comment: I checked the hashes, they are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is probably today the most efficient and convenient serialization/deserialization solution on Android and can be connected to many languages platforms.

As the alternatives mentioned here are java serialization and XML, I suggest you look at the chapter in the FAQ answering [Why use protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial?hl=fr).

[This article](http://www.4feets.com/2009/08/serializing-data-json-vs-protocol-buffers/) offers a small example of protobuf usage on android (and a kind of dubious benchmark comparison).